# Looking for short story anthology by a female editor. One story was about a business that created insects used to teach people

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

I checked this book out from the library a few years ago. The book seemed fairly recent, definitely after the year 2000. Probably after the year 2010. It was a paperback.

The editor was definitely female but I don't think it was specifically a collection of female writers only. I do think it had a lot of stories written by women. My girlfriend pulled it off the shelf because the stories were compiled by a female editor.

The only story I remember very clearly was about a person that worked in some sort of business crafting small insects that they would put into people's ears to teach them at night or help them with things? The main character fell out with the rest of their coworkers and was resistant to put one of the fabricated insects that their coworkers were using into their own ear?